# How to create a count plot from comma separated values of a column in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to create a count plot from the state names that appear in one of the columns of the google-sheet like following:

The open shareable google sheet link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=8060956

```
Column5
Dublin, OH
Chicago, IL
Chicago, IL, NY, FL
Atlanta,GA, DC,NY
Columbus, OH, NY
```

How to create the count plots using only the state names?

- The first word(s) before first comma is always city
- There can be space after commas.

**Required output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A),", ")),"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 matches '[A-Z][A-Z]|Remote' group by (Col1) order by Col1 ASC", -1)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Small update request:  can we also sort the states? SORT(values)? Then we will always have the same order of states.

Comment: Documentation for the formulas used:

[QUERY] (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[TRANSPOSE] (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en-GB)

[SPLIT] (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

[REGEXREPLACE] (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)

[TEXTJOIN] (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)

Comment: I appreciate the link, thanks a lot Daniel.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, what exactly do you want to order here? The states abbreviations in descending order?

Comment: @JvdV Yes that's correct, the descending order.

Comment: No worries. Also to answer you question about using sort, try wrapping the function in SORT() like this: =SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,E1:E),"[A-Z][a-z]+,|\s",""),",")),"Select Col1, count(Col1) group by (Col1)", -1))

Comment: Sorry for the messy format, the mini markdown doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @MilkyWay001, see the edit in the answer.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @JvdV  I am so sorry, unfortunately the formula did not work for the actual data. It works fine for dummy data, but it gave me strange state names for my actual data. I have updated the google sheet. I will truly appreciate some edit.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, I edited my answer to account for your full dataset. The only question about this I have is; what about the "Remote" values?

Comment: only the State is fine. Remote option will be not important after the covid ends (hopefully soon). But for the learning purpose, i would apprecieate the both solution.

Comment: @DanielH., for your information, by my understanding and experience `QUERY()` does return ascending sorted values by definition. A seperate `SORT()` function will also mess with the values. Better to do an descending order inside your query.

Comment: Here, I see that the SORT by values would make more sense than the sorting by state name, I would appreciate how we can sort by values, eg. first row is IL 22, and last row can be any state with only one count.

Comment: @MilkyWay001, `"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 matches '[A-Z][A-Z]|Remote' group by (Col1) order by count(Col1) desc"`

Comment: @JvdV This is super weird, the formula is sophisticated but I tried to apply for another case for the company sectors instead of states and it gives me weird result as shown in the googe sheet. ( I am sorry for taking a long time, but its really useful for me)

Comment: @MilkyWay001, it's a new question for complete different type of data but I edited your sheet for now =)